# How to inject load dump transient in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, automotive, transient, library

I wanted to simulate load dumping in LTspice by introducing a transient at load side. But I didn't find any block in LTspice library to do so.
Can anyone assist me in that regard?

Comment: You can either use a current source (be sure to use the `load` flag, if needed), or add switches controlled by sources, or behavioural resistors, or even the ISOxxx sources you see in the component browser; there are ways, you just need to make them as you need them.

Comment: Would an ideal switch + low ohmic resistor do the job for you?